# Blender 2.8 + Substance painter workflow

Tags: workflow

P/S Just started learning all the 3d stuff.

I want to create a human head in Blender 2.80 and texture it in Substance Painter.

*Are all the steps below correct or is there any easier way to do it? Just want to know how whole process looks step by step. Thanks for answer.*

1. Sculpting Head
2. Retopologize Head
3. UV unwrap retopo
4. Export retopo head (low poly) and original sculpted (high poly) meshes (FBX)
5. Import retopo head (low poly) to substance painter
6. Bake mesh maps (with high definition mesh selected (original sculpted head))
7. Texturing head
8. Apply exported textures in Blender
9. Render Head (Cycles)

Comment: Broadly speaking the workflow is fine. You may want to adjust some elements such as creating an ID Map.

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way. May be if you use the SBP's renderer.